# Envelope: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in sails.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, mongoose-populate, sails-mongo

Envelope: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in sails.js
Whenever i have have send create request they give me above error,
model : Car.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    engine: {
      type: 'String',
    },
    type: {
      type: 'String'
    },
    colors: {
      collection: 'color',
      via: 'car'
    }

  },
};
```

model : Color.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    color: {
      type: 'String',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    car: {
      model: 'car',
      required: true
    }
  },

};
```

CarController.js

please help me as fast as possible
bcz i have amateur learner in sails.js

```
create: async function (req, res) {
    let name = req.param('name');
    let engine = req.param('engine');
    let type = req.param('type');
  
    let colorName = req.param('color');

    if(!name){
      res.badRequest({err : 'invalid Name'});
    }
    if(!engine){
      res.badRequest({err : 'invalid Engine'});
    }
    if(!type){
      res.badRequest({err : 'invalid Type'});
    }
    if(!colorName){
      res.badRequest({err : 'invalid Color Name'});
    }


    await Car.create({
      name: name,
      engine: engine,
      type: type
    })
    .exec((err, newcar) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.serverError(err);
      }

      //Create New Color
        Color.create({
          color: colorName,
          car: newcar.id,
        })
        .exec((err, _color) => {
          if(err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
          }
        })
        res.send(newcar, _color);
    })
  },
```

It's look like id error, please solve as fast as possible

Comment: this is happening because 'newcar' is undefined. Check if Car.create really creates a car object.

Comment: I don't think you need the `await` since you do all the work in your callback anyway. I wonder if mixing `await` and `exec` is causing problems? You should be able to remove the `await` and have things still work.

Comment: Also... this seems like a funny data arrangement. You've got each car can have multiple colors, but one color can just have a single car. I think you may have meant to do that the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Lookups working in sails.js

```
find: async(req, res) => {
            try{
              let doc = await db.collection('color').aggregate([
                {
                  $lookup: {
                    from: 'car',
                    localField: 'carID',
                    foreignField: 'carID',
                    as: 'Car'
                  }
                }
              ]).toArray();
              res.ok(doc);
            } catch (error) {
          return res.badRequest(error);
        }
      }
```